# How do you echo a 4-digit Unicode character in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, character-encoding

I'd like to add the Unicode skull and crossbones to my shell prompt (specifically the **'SKULL AND CROSSBONES' (U+2620)**), but I can't figure out the magic incantation to make echo spit it, or any other, 4-digit Unicode character. Two-digit one's are easy. For example, `echo -e "\x55"`, .

In addition to the answers below it should be noted that, obviously, your terminal needs to support Unicode for the output to be what you expect. gnome-terminal does a good job of this, but it isn't necessarily turned on by default.

On macOS's Terminal app Go to Preferences-> Encodings and choose Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: Note that your *"2 digit one's are easy (to echo)"* comment is only valid for values up to  `"\x7F"` in a UTF-8 locale (which the `bash` tag suggests yours is)... patterns represented by a **single byte** are never in the range`\x80-\xFF`. This range is illegal in singl-byte UTF-8 chars. eg a Unicode Codepoint value of `U+0080` (ie. `\x80`) is actually 2 bytes in UTF-8.. `\xC2\x80`..

Comment: E.g. `printf "\\u007C\\u001C"`.

Comment: **NB:** for me in `gnome-terminal`, `echo -e '\ufc'` does not produce a ü, even with character encoding set to UTF-8. However, eg `urxvt` does print eg `printf "\\ub07C\\ub01C"` as expected (not with a � or box).

Comment: @Peter.O Why is the `bash` tag such a useful hint? Are different terminals common in CJK or … ?

Comment: @Peter.O zsh, fish, scsh, elvish, etc... there are many different shells, each can handle unicode characters however they want (or not). "bash" makes it clear this question isn't about some weird shell that does things differently.

Comment: `while read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done`

Answer (score 285, accepted):

In UTF-8 it's actually 6 digits (or 3 bytes).

```
$ printf '\xE2\x98\xA0'
☠
```

To check how it's encoded by the console, use hexdump:

```
$ printf ☠ | hexdump
0000000 98e2 00a0                              
0000003
```

Comment: Mine outputs "���" instead of ☠... Why is that?

Comment: @trusktr: you're not using UTF-8 terminal

Comment: That's true. I discovered i was using `LANG=C` instead of `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Now my terminals in Gnome show the symbols properly... The real terminals (tty1-6) still don't though.

Comment: For those people trying a hexdump: `0000000 f0 9f 8d ba` translates to `\xf0\x9f\x8d\xba`. Example echo: `echo -e "\xf0\x9f\x8d\xba"`.

Comment: You can also use the `$'...'` syntax to get the encoded character in to a variable without using a `$(...)` capturing subshell, for use in contexts that don't themselves interpret the escape sequences: `skull=$'\xE2\x98\xA0'`

Comment: @trusktr: `LANG=C` affects how the encoding is interpreted. When you use that, `"\xE2\x98\xA0"` gets interpreted as 3 high-range ASCII characters, instead of a single Unicode character composed of 3 code points. As for the "real" terminals (you mean virtual console TTYs, not actual hardware terminals, right?), maybe they're just using a font that doesn't have the ☠ glyph? They usually have pretty simple bitmap fonts.

Comment: Another thing about hexdump: on my machine, the second command in the answer outputs `0000000 98e2 00a0`. Of course the `0000000` is just an unimportant offset, but the bytes after it translate to `\xe2\x98\xa0`, because the machine uses the little endian byte order.

Comment: If your bash can output that characters below, goto:
http://unicode-table.com/en/#2591
And just copy it paste to your script, have fun.

Comment: I edited the answer from `printf "\xE2\x98\xA0"` to `printf '\xE2\x98\xA0'`. The result is the same, but it's an easier answer to understand, as you don't have to think about whether the shell is interpreting `\x` or not.

Comment: If you want to avoid endian order confusion, pipe to `xxd` instead of `hexdump`.  Output is then, `00000000: e298 a0` (same byte order as you entered).  `xxd` is typically provided on Linux with `vim`.  On macOS, it appears to come out-of-the-box (as does `vim`).

Answer (score 181):

```
% echo -e '\u2620'     # \u takes four hexadecimal digits
☠
% echo -e '\U0001f602' # \U takes eight hexadecimal digits
```

This works in Zsh (I've checked version 4.3) and in [Bash 4.2](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-02/msg00012.html#:%7E:text=UXXXXXXXX%20escape%20sequences) or newer.

Comment: that just spits out \u2620 when I do it.

Comment: For me too. Which shell are you using, Juliano?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that I use zsh.

Comment: Support for \u was added in Bash 4.2.

Comment: Supposedly works in fish as well according to the docs, but I can't get it to work. Easy enough to wrap in bash though.

Comment: @Flimm that would be `printf '\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'`

Comment: There is a version of this using ANSI-strings `echo $'\U1f602'`

Comment: does NOT work for me, Mac OS 10.14.2, bash (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)). It merely prints out the input - $ echo -e '\u2620' <enter> simply prints out:
\u2620

Comment: this works for newline as \n if you landed here for this like me. cant confirm for the post case.

Answer (score 75):

So long as your text-editors can cope with Unicode (presumably encoded in UTF-8) you can enter the Unicode code-point directly.

For instance, in the [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) text-editor you would enter insert mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and then the code-point number as a 4-digit hexadecimal number (pad with zeros if necessary). So you would type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. See: [What is the easiest way to insert Unicode characters into a document?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2254/467)

At a terminal running Bash you would type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and type in the hexadecimal code-point of the character you want. During input your cursor should show an underlined `u`. The first non-digit you type ends input, and renders the character. So you could be able to print U+2620 in Bash using the following:

<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

(The first enter ends Unicode input, and the second runs the `echo` command.)

Credit: [Ask Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents/32768#32768)

Comment: A good source for the hexademical code points is http://unicodelookup.com/#0x2620/1

Comment: The version of vim I'm using (7.2.411 on RHEL 6.3) doesn't respond as desired when there's a dot between the ctrl-v and the u, but works fine when that dot is omitted.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: I've removed the period from the instructions, it was not intended to be a key press (which is why it didn't appear with the keyboard effect). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Beware: this works in a terminal running Bash only if you're running it **under GTK+** environment, as Gnome.

Comment: The ability to `C-S-u 2 6 2 0` is a feature of your terminal emulator, X Input Method (XIM), or similar.  AFAIK, you will be unable to send both `SHIFT` and `CTRL` to the terminal layer.  The terminal only speaks in characters, rather than in keysyms and keycodes like your X server (also, its is 7-bit for all intents and purposes).  In this world, `CTRL` masks the 4 most significant bits (& 0b00001111) which results in

Comment: In vim, it is not `ctrl` + `v` + `u` all at once. It is rather `ctrl-v` and _then_ `u`. Lowercase `u` for at most four hex digits (example 03bb, λ), uppercase `U` for 8 hex digits (example 0001f4a9, ).

Answer (score 38):

Here's a fully internal Bash implementation, no forking, unlimited size of Unicode characters.

```
fast_chr() {
    local __octal
    local __char
    printf -v __octal '%03o' $1
    printf -v __char \\$__octal
    REPLY=$__char
}

function unichr {
    local c=$1    # Ordinal of char
    local l=0    # Byte ctr
    local o=63    # Ceiling
    local p=128    # Accum. bits
    local s=''    # Output string

    (( c < 0x80 )) && { fast_chr "$c"; echo -n "$REPLY"; return; }

    while (( c > o )); do
        fast_chr $(( t = 0x80 | c & 0x3f ))
        s="$REPLY$s"
        (( c >>= 6, l++, p += o+1, o>>=1 ))
    done

    fast_chr $(( t = p | c ))
    echo -n "$REPLY$s"
}

## test harness
for (( i=0x2500; i<0x2600; i++ )); do
    unichr $i
done
```

Output was:

```
─━│┃┄┅┆┇┈┉┊┋┌┍┎┏
┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛├┝┞┟
┠┡┢┣┤┥┦┧┨┩┪┫┬┭┮┯
┰┱┲┳┴┵┶┷┸┹┺┻┼┽┾┿
╀╁╂╃╄╅╆╇╈╉╊╋╌╍╎╏
═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟
╠╡╢╣╤╥╦╧╨╩╪╫╬╭╮╯
╰╱╲╳╴╵╶╷╸╹╺╻╼╽╾╿
▀▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█▉▊▋▌▍▎▏
▐░▒▓▔▕▖▗▘▙▚▛▜▝▞▟
■□▢▣▤▥▦▧▨▩▪▫▬▭▮▯
▰▱▲△▴▵▶▷▸▹►▻▼▽▾▿
◀◁◂◃◄◅◆◇◈◉◊○◌◍◎●
◐◑◒◓◔◕◖◗◘◙◚◛◜◝◞◟
◠◡◢◣◤◥◦◧◨◩◪◫◬◭◮◯
◰◱◲◳◴◵◶◷◸◹◺◻◼◽◾◿
```

Comment: I'm very curious the reasoning behind the round-about method, and the specific use of the REPLY variable.  I am assuming you inspected bash source or ran through  or something to optimize, which I can see how your choices could be optimizing, albeit highly dependent on the interpreter).

Comment: @nabin-info `$REPLY` is a wrong chocie is this case, Using small caps for variable name could be prefered in order to avoid mis interpretation. You could test to replace `sed 's/REPLY/anyVarname/g'` , script will work fine anyway.

Comment: `$REPLY` is the default output variable for the inbuilt `read` command. This solution doesn't use the `read` command, but `$REPLY` is as good as any name.  It is my observation that all-caps variable names in bash scripts often indicate 'external' thing, whether they be configuration options/globals, environment variables, or returns from other commands or functions.

Lowercase variables tend to be used locally.  This is purely my opinion, and you can use any variable name you like.

Answer (score 26):

Quick one-liner to convert UTF-8 characters into their 3-byte format:

```
var="$(echo -n '☠' | od -An -tx1)"; printf '\\x%s' ${var^^}; echo
```

or

```
echo -n '☠' | od -An -tx1 | sed 's/ /\\x/g'
```

The output of both is `\xE2\x98\xA0`, so you can write reversely:

```
echo $'\xe2\x98\xa0'   # ☠
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the above example *quick* (with 11 commands and their params)... Also it only handles 3 byte UTF-8 chars` (UTF-8 chars can be 1, 2, or 3 bytes)...  This is a bit shorter and works for 1-3++++ bytes: `printf "\\\x%s" $(printf '☠'|xxd -p -c1 -u)` .... *xxd* is shipped as part of the 'vim-common' package

Comment: PS: I just noticed that the above hexdump/awk example is swithching the sequence of bytes in a byte-pair.  This **does not** apply to a UTF-8 dump. It would be relavent if it were a dump of UTF-16LE and wanted to output Unicode **Codepoints**, but it doesn't make sense here as the input is UTF-8 and the output is exactly as input (plus the \x before each hexdigit-pair)

Comment: UTF-8 characters can be 1 - 4 bytes sequences

Comment: based on the comment of @Peter.O, I find the following, while bigger, pretty handy:
`hexFromGlyph(){
     if [ "$1" == "-n" ]; then outputSeparator=' '; shift; else outputSeparator='\n'; fi
     for glyph in "$@"; do printf "\\\x%s" $(printf "$glyph"|xxd -p -c1 -u); echo -n -e "$outputSeparator"; done
   }
# usage:
$ hexFromGlyph ☠ ✿
\xE2\x98\xA0
\xE2\x9C\xBF
$ hexFromGlyph -n ☠ ✿
\xE2\x98\xA0 \xE2\x9C\xBF`

Comment: Good god man.  Consider:  `codepoints () { printf 'U+%04x\n' ${@/#/\'}  ; } ; codepoints A Ｒ ☯    z`  ... enjoy    

Comment: @nabin-info Great, I was just to ask, how I could get the utf-16 representation, and that is it, your codepoints function does it. Thank you.

Comment: The quickest approach of all: Paste your emoji into the bash prompt and hit enter. Result: `bash: $'\342\230\240': command not found`

Answer (score 14):

Just put "☠" in your shell script. In the correct locale and on a Unicode-enabled console it'll print just fine:

```
$ echo ☠
☠
$
```

An ugly "workaround" would be to output the UTF-8 sequence, but that also depends on the encoding used:

```
$ echo -e '\xE2\x98\xA0'
☠
$
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a list of all unicode emoji's available:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks

Example:

```
echo -e "\U1F304"
```

For get the ASCII value of this character use hexdump

```
echo -e "" | hexdump -C

00000000  f0 9f 8c 84 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```

And then use the values informed in hex format

```
echo -e "\xF0\x9F\x8C\x84\x0A"
```

Comment: echoing the \U<hex> string doesn't work on OSX it just outputs exactly what's in the quotes.

Comment: The default bash version on macos (3.2.57 for me) predates the unicode feature. Update bash or use zsh.

Comment: The correct way of adding other normal chars would be with null char? `echo -e '\U2192\0abc'`?

Answer (score 10):

In bash to print a Unicode character to output use \x,\u or \U (first for 2 digit hex, second for 4 digit hex, third for any length)

```
echo -e '\U1f602'
```

I you want to assign it to a variable use $'...' syntax

```
x=$'\U1f602'
echo $x
```

Answer (score 9):

Any of these three commands will print the character you want in a console, provided the console do accept [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters (most current ones do):

```
echo -e "SKULL AND CROSSBONES (U+2620) \U02620"
echo $'SKULL AND CROSSBONES (U+2620) \U02620'
printf "%b" "SKULL AND CROSSBONES (U+2620) \U02620\n"

SKULL AND CROSSBONES (U+2620) ☠
```

After, you could copy and paste the actual glyph (image, character) to any (UTF-8 enabled) text editor.

If you need to see how such Unicode Code Point is encoded in UTF-8, use xxd (much better hex viewer than od):

```
echo $'(U+2620) \U02620' | xxd
0000000: 2855 2b32 3632 3029 20e2 98a0 0a         (U+2620) ....

That means that the UTF8 encoding is: e2 98 a0
```

Or, in HEX to avoid errors: 0xE2 0x98 0xA0. That is, the values between the space (HEX 20) and the Line-Feed (Hex 0A).

If you want a deep dive into converting numbers to chars: [look here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) to see an article from Greg's wiki (BashFAQ) about ASCII encoding in Bash!

Comment: re:"Or, in HEX to avoid errors..."  I hardly think that converting a unicode char to some binary encoding that you express in hex chars, **helps** avoid errors.  Using the unicode notation in "bash" would better avoid errors i.e.: " 
    \uHHHH---the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is  the
                 ----hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits);
    \UHHHHHHHH
                 ----the  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the
                 ----hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this:

```
$ echo -e '\u2620'
☠
```

This is pretty easier than searching a hex representation... I'm using this in my shell scripts. That works on gnome-term and urxvt AFAIK.

Comment: @masukomi if you know how to use brew you can install a more recent bash and use that.  The above works fine on my mac terminal when using the upgraded bash.

Comment: Yes, that's fine with newer versions of bash. Hower prompt strings, e.g $PS1 don't use echo escape formats

Answer (score 7):

## Playing with UTF8 in `bash`

Upgrade 2023...

### Print UTF8

From some time ago, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) use `%b` in `printf`:

```bash
printf %b\\n \\U1F600
```

### Store UTF8 into a variable

So you could assign a variable by using `-v` flag of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s `printf` builtin:

```bash
printf -v smiley \\U1F600
echo $smiley
```

#### Strictly answering SO question:

```bash
user@host:~$ printf -v skull %b '\U2620'
user@host:~$ PS1=${PS1/%\\$ /$skull\\$ }
user@host:~☠$
```

Could do the job. (Note `%b` is nearly useless)

### Showing part of table

Then for showing quickly some part of unicode table:

```bash
printf %b\\n \\U1F6{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{a..f}}|paste -d\  -{,,,}{,,,}
```

Showing *braille* part:

```bash
printf %b\\n \\U28{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{a..f}}|paste -d\  -{,,,}{,,,}
⠀ ⠁ ⠂ ⠃ ⠄ ⠅ ⠆ ⠇ ⠈ ⠉ ⠊ ⠋ ⠌ ⠍ ⠎ ⠏
⠐ ⠑ ⠒ ⠓ ⠔ ⠕ ⠖ ⠗ ⠘ ⠙ ⠚ ⠛ ⠜ ⠝ ⠞ ⠟
⠠ ⠡ ⠢ ⠣ ⠤ ⠥ ⠦ ⠧ ⠨ ⠩ ⠪ ⠫ ⠬ ⠭ ⠮ ⠯
⠰ ⠱ ⠲ ⠳ ⠴ ⠵ ⠶ ⠷ ⠸ ⠹ ⠺ ⠻ ⠼ ⠽ ⠾ ⠿
⡀ ⡁ ⡂ ⡃ ⡄ ⡅ ⡆ ⡇ ⡈ ⡉ ⡊ ⡋ ⡌ ⡍ ⡎ ⡏
⡐ ⡑ ⡒ ⡓ ⡔ ⡕ ⡖ ⡗ ⡘ ⡙ ⡚ ⡛ ⡜ ⡝ ⡞ ⡟
⡠ ⡡ ⡢ ⡣ ⡤ ⡥ ⡦ ⡧ ⡨ ⡩ ⡪ ⡫ ⡬ ⡭ ⡮ ⡯
⡰ ⡱ ⡲ ⡳ ⡴ ⡵ ⡶ ⡷ ⡸ ⡹ ⡺ ⡻ ⡼ ⡽ ⡾ ⡿
⢀ ⢁ ⢂ ⢃ ⢄ ⢅ ⢆ ⢇ ⢈ ⢉ ⢊ ⢋ ⢌ ⢍ ⢎ ⢏
⢐ ⢑ ⢒ ⢓ ⢔ ⢕ ⢖ ⢗ ⢘ ⢙ ⢚ ⢛ ⢜ ⢝ ⢞ ⢟
⢠ ⢡ ⢢ ⢣ ⢤ ⢥ ⢦ ⢧ ⢨ ⢩ ⢪ ⢫ ⢬ ⢭ ⢮ ⢯
⢰ ⢱ ⢲ ⢳ ⢴ ⢵ ⢶ ⢷ ⢸ ⢹ ⢺ ⢻ ⢼ ⢽ ⢾ ⢿
⣀ ⣁ ⣂ ⣃ ⣄ ⣅ ⣆ ⣇ ⣈ ⣉ ⣊ ⣋ ⣌ ⣍ ⣎ ⣏
⣐ ⣑ ⣒ ⣓ ⣔ ⣕ ⣖ ⣗ ⣘ ⣙ ⣚ ⣛ ⣜ ⣝ ⣞ ⣟
⣠ ⣡ ⣢ ⣣ ⣤ ⣥ ⣦ ⣧ ⣨ ⣩ ⣪ ⣫ ⣬ ⣭ ⣮ ⣯
⣰ ⣱ ⣲ ⣳ ⣴ ⣵ ⣶ ⣷ ⣸ ⣹ ⣺ ⣻ ⣼ ⣽ ⣾ ⣿
```

### Better into a little function

```bash
showU8_256() { 
    local i a
    for a ;do
        for i in {0..9} {A..F}; do
            printf '\\U%05Xx: %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b %b\n' \
                0x$a$i \\U$a${i}{{0..9},{A..F}}
        done
    done
}
```

Then

```
showU8_256 1f{3,4}
\U01F30x:                
\U01F31x:                
\U01F32x:                
\U01F33x:                
\U01F34x:                
\U01F35x:                
\U01F36x:                
\U01F37x:                
\U01F38x:                
\U01F39x:                
\U01F3Ax:                
\U01F3Bx:                
\U01F3Cx:                
\U01F3Dx:                
\U01F3Ex:                
\U01F3Fx:                
\U01F40x:                
\U01F41x:                
\U01F42x:                
\U01F43x:                
\U01F44x:                
\U01F45x:                
\U01F46x:                
\U01F47x:                
\U01F48x:                
\U01F49x:                
\U01F4Ax:                
\U01F4Bx:                
\U01F4Cx:                
\U01F4Dx:                
\U01F4Ex:                
\U01F4Fx:
```

### Browsing unicode table

For this, after searching reliable way, I'v finally posted on SuperUser [Dumping / browsing full unicode table](https://superuser.com/a/1784202/178656), my [python](/questions/tagged/python)  `dumpUnicode` script:

Shortly:

```bash
dumpUnicode() {
  python3 -c $'from unicodedata import name\nfor i in range(0x10FFFF):\n  try:
    var = name(chr(i))\n  except:\n    var = None\n  finally:\n    if var:
      print("\\\\U%06X: \47%s\47 %s" % (i,chr(i),var))'; }
```

```
dumpUnicode | grep SMIL.*SUNGLAS\\\|FONDUE
\U01F60E: '' SMILING FACE WITH SUNGLASSES
\U01FAD5: '' FONDUE
```

Or for strictly answering SO request:

```
dumpUnicode |grep "' SKULL AND CROSSBONES"
\U002620: '☠' SKULL AND CROSSBONES
```

### Converting to ASCII values

There is not *4 digit*, but a variable number of bytes:

```bash
printf -v skull '%b' \\U2620
LANG=C printf -v skull %q $skull
IFS=\' read -r _ skull _ <<<"$skull"
echo ${skull//\\/\\0}
```

```
\0342\0230\0240
```

```bash
echo -e ${skull//\\/\\0}
```

```
☠
```

As a function:

```bash
u8toBytes() { 
    local char
    printf -v char %b "$1"
    LANG=C printf -v char %q "$char"
    IFS=\' read -r _ char _ <<< "$char"
    echo ${char//\\/\\0}
    echo -e ${char//\\/\\0}
}
```

```
u8toBytes \\U2620
\0342\0230\0240
☠
u8toBytes \\UA0
\0302\0240
 
u8toBytes 
\0360\0237\0230\0216
```

### Further

Have a look at [Using Unicode specific character in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849805/1765658)

Answer (score 6):

You may need to encode the code point as octal in order for prompt expansion to correctly decode it.

U+2620 encoded as UTF-8 is E2 98 A0.

So in Bash,

```
export PS1="\342\230\240"
```

will make your shell prompt into skull and bones.

Comment: hi, what is the code that I should enter for "e0 b6 85"? how can I find it?

Comment: just convert the hexadecimal ( base 16 ) numbers e0 b6 85 into octal (base 8 ) - use a calculator is probably the easiest way to do this

Comment: e0 b6 85 hex is 340 266 205 octal

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! And btw, you can findal octal version at these pages: http://graphemica.com/%E2%9B%B5

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind a Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -CS -E 'say "\x{2620}"'
☠
```

`-CS` enables UTF-8 decoding on input and UTF-8 encoding on output. `-E` evaluates the next argument as Perl, with modern features like `say` enabled. If you don't want a newline at the end, use `print` instead of `say`.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for reviving this old question.  But when using `bash` there is a very easy approach to create Unicode codepoints from plain ASCII input, which even **does not fork** at all:

```
unicode() { local -n a="$1"; local c; printf -vc '\\U%08x' "$2"; printf -va "$c"; }
unicodes() { local a c; for a; do printf -vc '\\U%08x' "$a"; printf "$c"; done; };
```

Use it as follows to define certain codepoints

```
unicode crossbones 0x2620
echo "$crossbones"
```

or to dump the first 65536 unicode codepoints to stdout (takes less than 2s on my machine.  The additional space is to prevent certain characters to flow into each other due to shell's monospace font):

```
for a in {0..65535}; do unicodes "$a"; printf ' '; done
```

or to tell a little very typical parent's story (this needs Unicode 2010):

```
unicodes 0x1F6BC 32 43 32 0x1F62D 32 32 43 32 0x1F37C 32 61 32 0x263A 32 32 43 32 0x1F4A9 10
```

Explanation:

- `printf '\UXXXXXXXX'` prints out any Unicode character
- `printf '\\U%08x' number` prints `\UXXXXXXXX` with the number converted to Hex, this then is fed to another `printf` to actually print out the Unicode character
- `printf` recognizes octal (0oct), hex (0xHEX) and decimal (0 or numbers starting with 1 to 9) as numbers, so you can choose whichever representation fits best
- `printf -v var ..` gathers the output of `printf` into a variable, **without fork** (which tremendously speeds up things)
- `local variable` is there to not pollute the global namespace
- `local -n var=other` aliases `var` to `other`, such that assignment to `var` alters `other`.  One interesting part here is, that `var` is part of the local namespace, while `other` is part of the global namespace.

  - Please note that there is no such thing as `local` or `global` namespace in `bash`.  Variables are kept in the environment, and such are always global.  Local just puts away the current value and restores it when the function is left again.  Other functions called from within the function with `local` will still see the "local" value.  This is a fundamentally different concept than all the normal scoping rules found in other languages (and what `bash` does is very powerful but can lead to errors if you are a programmer who is not aware of that).

Comment: well -- doesn't work at all for me. any attempt to use any of your functions, emits: line 6: local: -n: invalid option
local: usage: local name[=value] ...
I'm using latest (10.14.2) MacOS and bash (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18))

Answer (score 5):

In Bash:

```sh
UnicodePointToUtf8()
{
    local x="$1"               # ok if '0x2620'
    x=${x/\\u/0x}              # '\u2620' -> '0x2620'
    x=${x/U+/0x}; x=${x/u+/0x} # 'U-2620' -> '0x2620'
    x=$((x)) # from hex to decimal
    local y=$x n=0
    [ $x -ge 0 ] || return 1
    while [ $y -gt 0 ]; do y=$((y>>1)); n=$((n+1)); done
    if [ $n -le 7 ]; then       # 7
        y=$x
    elif [ $n -le 11 ]; then    # 5+6
        y=" $(( ((x>> 6)&0x1F)+0xC0 )) \
            $(( (x&0x3F)+0x80 ))" 
    elif [ $n -le 16 ]; then    # 4+6+6
        y=" $(( ((x>>12)&0x0F)+0xE0 )) \
            $(( ((x>> 6)&0x3F)+0x80 )) \
            $(( (x&0x3F)+0x80 ))"
    else                        # 3+6+6+6
        y=" $(( ((x>>18)&0x07)+0xF0 )) \
            $(( ((x>>12)&0x3F)+0x80 )) \
            $(( ((x>> 6)&0x3F)+0x80 )) \
            $(( (x&0x3F)+0x80 ))"
    fi
    printf -v y '\\x%x' $y
    echo -n -e $y
}

# test
for (( i=0x2500; i<0x2600; i++ )); do
    UnicodePointToUtf8 $i
    [ "$(( i+1 & 0x1f ))" != 0 ] || echo ""
done
x='U+2620'
echo "$x -> $(UnicodePointToUtf8 $x)"
```

Output:

```
─━│┃┄┅┆┇┈┉┊┋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛├┝┞┟
┠┡┢┣┤┥┦┧┨┩┪┫┬┭┮┯┰┱┲┳┴┵┶┷┸┹┺┻┼┽┾┿
╀╁╂╃╄╅╆╇╈╉╊╋╌╍╎╏═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟
╠╡╢╣╤╥╦╧╨╩╪╫╬╭╮╯╰╱╲╳╴╵╶╷╸╹╺╻╼╽╾╿
▀▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█▉▊▋▌▍▎▏▐░▒▓▔▕▖▗▘▙▚▛▜▝▞▟
■□▢▣▤▥▦▧▨▩▪▫▬▭▮▯▰▱▲△▴▵▶▷▸▹►▻▼▽▾▿
◀◁◂◃◄◅◆◇◈◉◊○◌◍◎●◐◑◒◓◔◕◖◗◘◙◚◛◜◝◞◟
◠◡◢◣◤◥◦◧◨◩◪◫◬◭◮◯◰◱◲◳◴◵◶◷◸◹◺◻◼◽◾◿
U+2620 -> ☠
```

Answer (score 4):

The `printf` builtin (just as the coreutils' `printf`) knows the `\u` escape sequence which accepts 4-digit Unicode characters:

```
   \uHHHH Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character with hex value HHHH (4 digits)
```

Test with Bash 4.2.37(1):

```
$ printf '\u2620\n'
☠
```

Comment: printf is also a shell built-in. You're probably using the default macOS bash (v3). Try with `\printf` to use the standalone executable, or try with upgraded bash

Answer (score 3):

Based on Stack Overflow questions *[Unix cut, remove first token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428443)* and *https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903654/781312*:

```
(octal=$(echo -n ☠ | od -t o1 | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed -e 's#\([0-9]\+\) *#\\0\1#g')
echo Octal representation is following $octal
echo -e "$octal")
```

Output is the following.

```
Octal representation is following \0342\0230\0240
☠
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy with a Python2/3 one-liner:

```
$ python -c 'print u"\u2620"'    # python2
$ python3 -c 'print(u"\u2620")'  # python3
```

Results in:

```
☠
```

Answer (score 1):

If hex value of unicode character is known

```
H="2620"
printf "%b" "\u$H"
```

If the decimal value of a unicode character is known

```
declare -i U=2*4096+6*256+2*16
printf -vH "%x" $U              # convert to hex
printf "%b" "\u$H"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean windows bash-like apps such as msys2, you can use :

`[Alt ( Hold ) ] + [decimal Numbers] + [Alt (Release)]`

to input a HTML typed code such as : , `&#129392;` It would echo to visual properly.

Similarly, in productive software you can use that method too.