# Unix cut, remove first token

Tags: unix, cut

I'm trying to use Unix [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29) to remove the first two fields per line. I have input lines of of the form

(token)(whitespace)(token)(lots of text)

The problem is that there exit `n` tokens per line, so I can't do something like this

```
cut -f3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Is there a way to tell cut to take `everything except` the specified fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cut -d' ' -f3-
```

-d' ' might be required.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -f3-
```

[Body is too short? Is that new?]

Comment: -d' ' is not required?
I think cut -d' ' -f3- would be it.

Comment: If `-d` is not given, it defaults to tabs. Actually, if "whitespace" can be both tabs and spaces, neither is right.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer `cut -d' '-f3-` but it did not exclude the field. The below command worked though. I am using Linux SLES.

`cut -d' ' -f3 --complement`

Reference link https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6867/exclude-a-column-with-cut

Happy to be corrected and learn. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for this:

```
   awk '{$1=$2=""}1' file
```