# How to make special characters in a Bash script for conky?

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, special-characters

I wonder how can I make a Celsius character in my bash script, so I could correct the output in "CPU temp: 50 C" line?
What are the escape sequences for this kind of special characters, providing my font supports them?

Still scratching my head...

To be more precise I need it to use in conky
I use this line: awk '{printf($3" C")}'. How should I correct it so that it outputs Celsius degree?
Cause if I insert ℃ character directly, conky screws it.

Answer (score 16):

All non-control sequences of bytes your script outputs to the terminal are interpreted for display according to the terminal's settings. If you configure it to interpret incoming data as [utf-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) then all you need to do in your bash script is output the Celsius character as required by [utf-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Setting your terminal right depends on the application you're using. It is quite likely that it is already in utf-8 mode.

In order to display the character you want you need to look up its Unicode codepoint and encode it in utf-8 or you can look it up somewhere where character's utf-8 sequence is already shown. Celsius character is described [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2103/index.htm) for example.

Celsius utf-8 sequence is 0xE2 0x84 0x83, so you can display it in your shell using the `$'string'` construct since it accepts the `\xhh` escape:

```
$ echo $'\xe2\x84\x83'
℃
```

or echo with -e:

```
$ echo -e '\xe2\x84\x83'
℃
```

Also, you can assign it to a variable

```
$ CEL=$'\xe2\x84\x83'
$ echo $CEL
℃
```

If you wish to display ℃ as two separate characters: degree character and the C letter then you can use [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) and this command:

```
$ echo $'\xc2\xb0'C
°C
```

If you're using a shell which doesn't support the `$'string'` construct, you can also use utilities like perl or python:

```
$ python -c 'print "\xe2\x84\x83"'
℃
$ perl -e 'print "\xe2\x84\x83\n"'
℃
```

In GNU `awk` you can use standard C language escapes including `\xhh`, for example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\xe2\x84\x83"; }' 
℃
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\xc2\xb0\C"; }' 
°C
```

Note that an extra backslash was needed to terminate the hexadecimal number (without it the escape sequence consumes all hexadecimal digits including letter C, see [GNU awk user's guide](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html)).

More portable solution in `awk` is to use octal sequence. Since hexadecimal 0xC2 is octal 302 and hexadecimal 0xB0 is octal 260, you can do the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\302\260C"; }'
°C
```

Similarly,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\342\204\203"; }'
℃
```

Comment: I'm not able to find any reference to the `$'string'` construct; what's its exact name, or where is it documented?

Comment: The only problem with using the [degree symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol) is that it **look really bad** in the terminal environment, because of font-size incompatibility problems when using UNICODE.

Answer (score 3):

Bash now supports Unicode escape sequences using `\u`:

```
echo -e "\u00b0"
```

will print

```
°
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
echo -e "CPU temp: 50\xE2\x84\x83"
```

Related: [How do you echo a 4-digit Unicode character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash)