# Unicode support in Eclipse GGTS IDE editor (how to input unicode math symbols)

Tags: eclipse, unicode, groovy

I would like to deal with [floral formulae](http://www.academia.edu/1175371/Floral_formulae_updated_for_routine_inclusion_in_formal_taxonomic_descriptions) by my DSL coded in [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org), so I need some special symbols such as [female sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2640/index.htm) and [Superscripts and Subscripts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

Thanks to the [great answers that I found on stackoverflow questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash) now I'm able to 
insert special unicode symbols in source code in VIM (MacVim) this way:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>.

However, **I would like to be able to do the same in Eclipse IDE** (I'm trying to use [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE to develop a grails project)

**Question**: How can I insert in the Eclipse editor a 4 digit unicode symbol by knowing the encoding ( without cut & paste from another source) ?

Comment: $ Groovy Version: 2.0.5 JVM: 1.7.0_06 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X   $ Grails version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be a few ways to get the unicode characters on a Mac.  The first few don't appear to be what you want exactly, but included for completeness.

1) Make sure System Preferences->Keyboard "show keyboard & character viewers in menu bar" is selected.  Then you can click on that (normally accessible via option+cmd+T, but not in eclipse) to get the Character Viewer.  You can then double-click a special character you want and it should insert at cursor.

2) Under the default setup, you should be able to click Option + key to get an alternate character.  Use the keyboard viewer from #1 to see what maps to what.  Note you can switch to some more mappings using Shift at the same time.  This will only get you a subset of unicode characters.

3) From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard):  Under System Preferences->Languages & Text, go to Input Sources tab.  Select the Unicode Hex Input source.  You may need to assign switching input sources (under System Prefs->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts->Keyboard) to a hotkey combo (default probably conflicts with spotlight, so change to something else).  After that, you should be able to use said hotkey combo to switch to the Unicode Input Source - in that mode, you can hold Option down and enter a hex 4-digit key code, which will result in the character being placed at cursor.