# How do I convert among printed decimal/octal/hex/UTF-8 representations of a UTF-8 character from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, utf-8, hex, octal

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596741/is-there-a-tool-equivalent-to-ascii1-but-for-utf-8) someone suggested `echo -e` with `\0<sequence>` for octal, and `\x<sequence>` for hex.  E.g.:

`echo -e "\\0302\\0241"`  --> `¡`

Is there a simple way to convert in the other direction, from UTF-8 character to printed octal/hex sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - use `hexdump`, like this:

```
$ echo -n i | hexdump
```

Which will output something like this:

```
0000000 0069                              
0000003
```

For something more formatted, you could do this:

```
$ echo ü | hexdump | awk '{print "\\x"toupper(substr($2,3,4)) "\\x"toupper(substr($2,0,2)) "\\x"toupper(substr($3,3,4))}' | head -1
```

which will print out this:

```
\xC3\xBC\x0A
```

Code taken from here: [How do you echo a 4-digit Unicode character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash)

Comment: That's great.  And for octal: `echo ¡ | hexdump -b`; decimal: `echo ¡ | hexdump -d`.