# How to use git pickaxe option with special characters like 'ñ or á' in ANSI encoded files?

Tags: git

I want to find changes on my commits and the word I'm looking for has an accent: `Línea`.

`git log -p -SLínea` returns no result.

How **i can escape** special characters no git pickaxe option in a ANSI encoded file?

**Notes:**
 * I'm using Git Bash for windows (Portable Git version 1.9.5)
 * File is encoded in ANSI. I have tested with a file UTF-8 encoded and works.

---

**Edit**
@LeGEC solution with regular expressions works:
`git log -S"Li.nea" --pickaxe-regex`

Now I wonder if i can escape special characters or have to use regex and `.` every special character.

Comment: Have you tried simply typing the character in your shell ? If the shell handles utf8 correctly, and the text is in utf8, this should work. Works for me (looking for `é` using bash/linux).

Comment: No that there are two ways how you can encode Línea in UTF-8: using the character `í` or using just plain `i` together with the combining mark.

Comment: I see. Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash) help ?  
A quick hack may be to look for `-S"Li.nea"`

Comment: @LeGEC,@choroba I can typing 'í' in my shell. The problem seems to be that file is ANSI encoded.

@LeGeC, I guess you meant `-S"L.nea"` but -S option does not support regex expressions

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack is to look for `"Li.nea"` (`i` followed by any character) which can catch other words, but will roughly work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955592/86072) worked for me (bash / linux) to type specific Unicode points in the shell (Ctrl+Shift+U, 0, 3, 0, 1).

Tried the following with plain grep :

```
$ echo -e "Li\xCC\x81nea"
Línea
$ echo -e "Li\xCC\x81nea" | grep "Linea" 
# no match here
$ echo -e "Li\xCC\x81nea" | grep "Línea" # I typed "i" then "Ctrl+Shift+U, 0, 3, 0, 1"
Línea     # match
$ echo -e "Li\xCC\x81nea" | grep "Li.nea"
Línea     # match
```

---

for the regex part : `git log -S"Li.nea" --pickaxe-regex`

---

If the file is ISO-8859-1 encoded, you should probably look for the correct sequence of bytes. ISO-8859-1 for `í` is `0xED` :

```
$ word=`echo -e "L\xEDnea" # ISO-8859 for Línea
$ echo $word
L�nea  # expected : the shell tries to print utf8 characters, 0xED is not correct
$ git log -S${word} #hopefully works ?
```

Comment: Thanks, regex works with `git log -S"L.nea" --pickaxe-regex` (dot replaces i). Unicode don't works again. Probably because in ANSI files, every character is a byte and i'm findind more of a byte with Unicode.